# How to load data.sql in spring boot 3 application? I guess DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer has been removed from springboot 3 version

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I have simple springboot application with following dependencies

1. web
2. h2
3. data jpa

trying to load data.sql for Student entity. Beow is application.properties

> server.port: 8080
>
> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:javatpoint
> spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
> spring.datasource.username=sa
> spring.datasource.password=
> spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
> #enabling the H2 console
> spring.h2.console.enabled=true
>
> spring.jpa.show-sql=true
>
> spring.datasource.data=classpath:/data.sql
> spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

when i run my springboot application I am getting bean creation exception for dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer. My guess is DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer is removed in springboot 3 version onwards. otherwise this would have worked with 2.x.x version.

Is there any walkaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find your answer here on Baeldung:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql
As you can see over their github you Just need to put the data.sql on your classepath and put the property:
spring.sql.init.mode=always.

You can get rid of these properties on your application.properties:
spring.datasource.data=classpath:/data.sql spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

Be aware that if you are using hibernate you need to defer data initialization with this:
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true